# @Async test exception case

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

I have to test this code for throwing exception, cause method is annotated by @Async exceptions does not throw

```
@Async
    public CompletableFuture<Response> method(Req req) {
        Response response = method(req);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(response);
    }

private Response anotherMethod(Request req) {
        String uri = getUrl();

       Response response = restTemplate.postForObject(//some params);
        if (response == null) {
            throw new RemoteServiceException();
        }
        if (!response.isOk()) {
            throw new RemoteServiceException(ErrorCodeConstant.Exception,
                    "some message");
        }
        return response;
    }
```

How i can get testing exception cases in private method?

Answer (score 0):

Since your private method derives its response from a call to resttemplate, you can mock out resttemplate.  You didn't list your class logic, so I'm going to make some assumptions here that your class is named `SomeClass` and you are injecting a `RestTemplate` into it.  Also, I assume that the code you've added in your question is not your actual code because in your async method, it's just calling itself, this will result in a StackOverflow.

Your test would look like this (with Junit4, you can do the same with 5 but I'm assuming 4 since you're still using RestTemplate).  This also makes the assumption that you meant to call `anotherMethod` from `method`.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeClassTest {

  @Mock
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @InjectMocks
  private SomeClass someclass;

  @Test(expected = RemoteServiceException.class)
  public void method_restTemplateValidResponse() {

     when(restTemplate.postForObject(/* your matches here */)).thenReturn(null);

     Req req = new Req();
     someClass.method(req);
  }
}
```

Comment: i can write tests on my method if that be non async and u did the same, i need example to how i can test exceptions cases considering that public method is ASYNC

Comment: Well, partner, if you look closely at your code, in the event of an exception, there is no CompletableFuture because the exception occurs on this line: `Response response = method(req);` and since you aren't catching that, it's being thrown from your `method(Req req)` method before the CompletableFuture is created.  If you want the exception in your CompletableFuture, then you need to supply it with a supplier, e.g. the method you're calling, like this: `return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> anotherMethod(req))`

Comment: i wrote test which must throw exception but cause method is annoted @async exception doesn`t thrown, how i could test exception case?

Comment: i just tried your test thats doesn`t work for my case

Comment: Unless you're writing an integration test, the `@Async` annotation isn't factoring into your test, and unless you refactor your method, your exception will not be included in your CompletableFuture because the exception bubbles up and is thrown before the future is created.